# Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5.12 and am getting this error - possible dependency issue

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file where I have upgraded to Spring Boot 2.5.12. Do I need to update or add any other dependencies?

```
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.22.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.strati.tunr.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>strati-af-tunr-utils-client-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${ccm.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openpojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpojo</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

getting this issue when running

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
> reactor.util.context.ContextView     at 
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) 
> at 
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) 
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) 
> ... 87 more

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts by deleting so much content that the answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: had to redact some information - have raised a flag for this and am awaiting status on that - have edited post again accordingly...

Comment: have left in dependencies only, is this alright? - can add the other information if required

Comment: If the question is about running unit tests then the pom should really run unit tests otherwise you'll get comments and answers saying that's missing and that's your problem. You need to leave a [mcve] here which is what you had originally - at least it was reproducible.

Comment: have added in the other information - could you assist with covering the history (redact it - so that sensitve info is not visible) - if not possible can I close/delete this question?

Comment: Only a moderator [can assist you with that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419679/1038015).

Comment: This is one of the subjects of [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381100/have-had-some-questions-with-sensitive-info-i-accidentally-posted-it-wont-let). [The other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71995405/have-updated-spring-to-2-5-12-however-my-project-isnt-running-and-says-no-juni) was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update this dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.22.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

to version 3.4.x as Spring Boot 2.5.12 uses *reactor.netty* 1.0.18 which relies on *reactor-core* 3.4.x (compare with *[NoClassDefFoundError for reactor.util.context.ContextView using an HttpClient with reactor-netty-core and reactor-netty-http #1388](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1388)*), but you force Maven to use an older *reactor-core* version.